# How to select only objects fully contained in selection rectangle?

Tags: fabricjs

I want to change behavior of my FabricJS canvas so when I drag a selection rectangle **from left to right**, it will select only objects which are fully contained within.

If I drag selection rectangle **from right to left**, I want to select all objects which intersect with that rectangle. (This is standard behavior of FabricJS.)

Any idea how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: You could add custom behavior on selection, then detect which case (left to right or right to left) occurs, and finally remove from selection objects which only intersect and aren't fully inside selection (in the first case).

Note that IIRC fabric selection includes by default objects which intersect selection area.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You should change selectionFullyContained property to true on canvas according to selection direction.

Fabric.js Docs: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#selectionFullyContained

However there is no option for separate right to left and left to right selections. 
You can overwrite fabric libarary collectObjects method to extend the behavior.
I attached an example for that below.

In my example it is possible with passing **selectionDirection** wih value **"fromLeft"** or **"fromRight"**
If you omit this option it will work the both direction

```js
fabric.Canvas.prototype._collectObjects = function(e) {
  let group = [];
  let currentObject;
  let x1 = this._groupSelector.ex;
  let y1 = this._groupSelector.ey;
  let x2 = x1 + this._groupSelector.left;
  let y2 = y1 + this._groupSelector.top;
  let selectionX1Y1;
  let selectionX2Y2;
  let selectionX1;
  let selectionY1;
  let selectionX2;
  let selectionY2;
  let currentDirection;
  if (this.selectionDirection) {
    if (x1 < x2) {
      currentDirection = "fromLeft" 
      selectionX1 = x1;
      selectionX2 = x2;
    } else {
      currentDirection = "fromRight"
      selectionX1 = x2;
      selectionX2 = x1;
    }
    if (this.selectionDirection !== currentDirection) {
      return [];
    }
  }
 
  if (!this.selectionDirection) {
    selectionX1 = Math.min(x1, x2);
    selectionX2 = Math.max(x1, x2);
  }
  selectionY1 = Math.min(y1, y2);
  selectionY2 = Math.max(y1, y2);
  selectionX1Y1 = new fabric.Point(selectionX1,selectionY1);
  selectionX2Y2 = new fabric.Point(selectionX2, selectionY2);  
  let allowIntersect = !this.selectionFullyContained;
   
  let isClick = x1 === x2 && y1 === y2; 
  
  // we iterate reverse order to collect top first in case of click.
  for (let i = this._objects.length; i--; ) {
    currentObject = this._objects[i];

    if (!currentObject || !currentObject.selectable || !currentObject.visible) {
      continue;
    }


    if ((allowIntersect && currentObject.intersectsWithRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2)) ||
        currentObject.isContainedWithinRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) ||
       
       (allowIntersect && currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX1Y1)) ||
        (allowIntersect && currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX2Y2))
    ) {
      group.push(currentObject);
      // only add one object if it's a click
      
      if (isClick) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (group.length > 1) {
    group = group.filter(function(object) {
      return !object.onSelect({ e: e });
    });
  }

  return group;
}

const elementId = "canvasID";
const setupOptions = {
  selectionFullyContained: true,
  selectionColor: 'rgba(255, 187, 127, 0.05)',
  selectionBorderColor: 'black',
  selectionDirection: "fromLeft", // or fromLeft
};
const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(elementId, setupOptions);
const rect = new fabric.Rect({left: 20, strokeWidth: 0, top: 20, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red'});
fabricCanvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

    <canvas id="canvasID" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvasID" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Kindly, post some samples! @Kombye

Comment: Thanks @kombye. I have upvoted the question and your answer